# how to ignore particular child node when select the root node in xslt?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

current coding given in this picture, I want ignore the `<bookmeta>` content in output how is possible
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXF1H.png)

Comment: You should really edit your question to show you XML and you XSLT, rather than link to an image that might disappear at some point in the future. To add XML/XSLT samples to your question, just copy in the text, select it, and then click the `{}` button to format it to make it readable. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to do this. In your situation I would either change the template to match `<book>` instead of the root (remember - the built-in templates will automatically handle the root for you) and use the `except` operator or I would write a template to suppress the `bookMeta` element.

**Approach 1**

```
<xsl:template match="book">
    <!-- you probably want to add some sort of output element here! -->
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node() except bookMeta"/>
</xsl:template>
```

**Approach 2**

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="bookMeta"/>
```

I would suggest using the second approach normally - you have made no changes to the original template and, if you want to handle `bookMeta` later you have isolated your changes.

Comment: I know about this 2nd approach, can you explain about 1st approach, its not worked here

Comment: Bear in mind that the way I wrote that means that you would replace the template matching the document node with the one matching the root element. Also, remember that `xsl:apply-templates` without a `select` attribute is the same as selecting `node()`. The `except` operator allows you to exclude nodes from a sequence. The sequence of nodes here would be all child nodes except those that match the RHS of `except`. What do you mean by "its not worked here"?

Comment: Thank You Nic Gibson finally I got solution             <xsl:template name="main">
    <fo:block>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()/*[not(name()='bookMeta') and not(name()='RSuiteMetadata')]"/>
    </fo:block>
  </xsl:template>

Comment: That's a long winded way of stating the first example I gave - although it will work in XSLT 1.0 and suffers from potential namespace problems.